# Whats the purpose served by the strange bitwise operator combo?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I was going through the following code and came across the following snippet.

https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/EFI/Firmware/MdeModulePkg/Core/Pei/Hob/Hob.c

```
EFI_STATUS  
EFIAPI  
PeiCreateHob (  
  IN CONST EFI_PEI_SERVICES  **PeiServices,  
  IN UINT16            Type,  
  IN UINT16            Length,  
  IN OUT VOID          **Hob  
  )  
{  
  EFI_STATUS                           Status;  
  EFI_HOB_HANDOFF_INFO_TABLE           *HandOffHob;  
  EFI_HOB_GENERIC_HEADER               *HobEnd;  
  EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS                 FreeMemory;  


  Status = PeiGetHobList (PeiServices, Hob);  
  if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {  
    return Status;  
  }

  HandOffHob = *Hob;  

  //
  // Check Length to avoid data overflow.
  //
  if (0x10000 - Length <= 0x7) {  
    return EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER;  
  }
  Length     = (UINT16)((Length + 0x7) & (~0x7));  
  ...
```

I don't get what we are achieving with the following operation:

```
Length     = (UINT16)((Length + 0x7) & (~0x7));
```

I know that the length would be 16 bit aligned. But why are we ANDing with all zeros? We would be losing the LSB 3 bits in the operation as I understand. What's the use of this operation?

Comment: Write down the "equation" on paper and solve it for a few random values of `Length` and see what they become.

Comment: I am getting multiples of 8. Like 1000 for length=2 ,0010 0000 for length=21 etc

Comment: All-uppercase names are typically used for macros only. You should reconsider your naming conventions. And don't use homebrew names for fixed width types. Use `stdint.h`.

Comment: @Olaf While good advice, none of this is the OP's code, and thusly none of it is the OP's naming conventions, nor use of OP's homebrewed names. This is all from the vbox efi firmware toolkit.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for the info. That explains a lot of the problems and queirks with EFI ... (bad naming style often comes with bad architecture and bad code in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Length = (UINT16)((Length + 0x7) & (~0x7));`

The operation performs two significant steps:

- Performs a round-up by carry to bits above the lower three bits of `Length`
- Ensures the lower three bits are then empty, thereby making the result the closest multiple of 8 equal to, or greater than, the original `Length` value.

**Part 1: Rounding Up**

If the lower three bits of `Length` are in anyway lit (anything besides `000`), an increment by `0x7` (`111` in binary) will propagate via carry to the bits above the lower three. For `000` in the lower three bits, the lower three bits simply become `111` and there is no carry. For example:

```
 5 - 00000101
 7 - 00000111
=============
12 - 00001100
         ^-------note carry
```

Another example:

```
250 -  11111010
  7 -  00000111
===============
257 - 100000001
```

And finally, an example that is already clear on the lower three bits (and therefore a multiple of 8):

```
24 - 00011000
 7 - 00000111
=============
31 - 00011111
```

---

**Part 2: Culling Lower Bits**

Once the value is rounded up, the lower three bits are culled to ensure the final result is a multiple of 8. Using the examples we had before

```
   5 - 00000101
+  7 - 00000111
===============
  12 - 00001100
& ~7 - 11111000
===============
   8   00001000
```

Next example

```
 250 -  11111010
+  7 -  00000111
================
 257 - 100000001
& ~7 - 111111000
================
 256 - 100000000
```

And our final example:

```
  24 - 00011000
+  7 - 00000111
===============
  31 - 00011111
& ~7 - 11111000
===============
  24 - 00011000
```

In summary, this simply sets `Length` to be the closest value equal-to or above the current value that is a multiple of `8`. That's it.

Comment: Almost sounds like a "find the next logical sector" routine.